# Can someone to extract in specific group of words from each line

Tags: python, list, split

i have list which has the following words stored . How Can i seperate the sentence inside the   [    and  ]  for example in dash[0] what i need to sperate is The Sunday Profile: Panth meets Wealth from the rest. I want to do that in each group and store it .   -

```
dash = ['{"Headlines": ["The Sunday Profile: Panth meets Wealth"]}\n', '{"Headlines": ["Wage no bar"]}\n']
```

i have tried-

```
 for line in f:
    text = line
            
    

print(text)
```

but that prints only the last line

Comment: can you share whats the expected output?

Comment: please create a [mre]. You defined `dash` but don't use it, then `f` is not defined.

Comment: For one, your indentation is a mess - from what you shared, it looks like the `print()` call is outside the loop. Assuming `f` is actually supposed to be `dash`, that would work, although there seems to be very little point in assigning each value to a variable first, if all you're doing is printing it immediately after - you may as well print `line` itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that converts the string to a dictionary and returns the first item of the value

```py
import json
def get_first_item(s):
    return json.loads(s).values()[0][0]
```

Then map the function to the list

```py
for line in map(get_first_item, dash):
    print(line)
```

gives

```sh
The Sunday Profile: Panth meets Wealth
Wage no bar
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from ast import literal_eval
dash = ['{"Headlines": ["The Sunday Profile: Panth meets Wealth"]}\n', 
'{"Headlines": ["Wage no bar"]}\n']
for i in dash:
    print(literal_eval(i)["Headlines"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that in the future you follow StackOverflow's guidance on [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You should also be sure to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

With that said, assuming the values in the `dash` list are always json and there is always one headline, you could use a list comprehension to get a new list of all headlines.

```
import json

dash = ['{"Headlines": ["The Sunday Profile: Panth meets Wealth"]}\n', '{"Headlines": ["Wage no bar"]}\n']

headlines = [json.loads(x)["Headlines"][0] for x in dash]
```

The new variable `headlines` would have all of the items you are looking for.  If `Headlines` from the `dash` list can have more than one value, I'd recommend just leaving them as lists and dropping the `[0]` index from the stated solution.